# Background not displaying

Tags: html, css, css-tables

The background on this page isn't displaying and instead just shows the image i have set behind the background. Also I tried centering my table using the methods posted on other threads, but none of them worked for this specifically.

```css
/* 
   Winter, Edwards, and Boyd style sheet 
   Filename: styles.css

   Author:   Justus Self
   Date:     4/27/2017
   Long giant project
 */

/* reset styles */
html {
   font-size: 16px;
}
a, article, audio, body, div, figcaption, figure, footer, header, h1, 
h2, h3, img, li, nav, p, section, source, ul, video {
   border: 0;
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
}
img, video {
   max-width: 100%;
   height: auto;
   width: auto;
}
ul {
   list-style-type: none;
}

/* document-wide styles */
body {
   margin: 0 auto;
   font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
p {
   line-height: 1.4em;
   font-size: 1.3em;
}
a:link {
   color: black;
}
a:visited {
   color: #888;
}

/* skip navigation link */
p.skipnavigation a {
   position: absolute;
   left: -10000px;
}
p.skipnavigation a:focus {
   color: ivory;
   background-color: #34180f;
   top: 0.4em;
   left: auto;
   right: 0.4em;
   z-index: 2;
}

/* header section */
h1 {
   text-align: center;
   font-family: Bitter, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
   font-weight: 700;
   color: ivory;
   background-color: white;
   font-size: 2.4em;
}

/* site navigation bar */
nav {
   color: #34180f;
   text-align: center;
   background-color: #B8944D;
}
nav li {
   margin: 0.3em 0.5em;
   display: inline-block;
   font-size: 1.3em;
   line-height: 1.4em;
}
nav a:link {
   text-decoration: none;
   color: #744f42;
}
nav a:visited {
   color: #744f42;
}
nav a:hover, nav a:focus {
   color: ivory;
}
nav ul, nav div, nav iframe {
   display: inline-block;
   vertical-align: middle;
}
#AboutUs:hover {
 color: ivory;
 cursor: pointer;
}
#AboutUs {
 color: #744f42;
}

/* main content */
article {
   margin: 0 auto;
   padding: 1.4em;
   background: #7eccec;
   background: url("images/bg.jpg");
}
article div {
   max-width: 854px;
   margin: 0 auto;
   padding: 0 3% 1em;
   background-color: ivory;
   overflow: auto;
}
article div.welcome {
   padding-top: 2em;
}
article div figure {
 float: left;
 padding-right: 2%;
 padding-bottom: 2%
 margin-top: 20px;
}
.container {
   min-width: 600px;
   max-width: 800px;
   margin: 0 auto;
   padding: 0 3% 0;
   background-color: darkblue;
   overflow: auto;
}
h2 {
   padding: 0.4em;
   text-align: left;
   font-family: Bitter, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
   font-size: 2em;
   font-weight: 700;
}
h3 {
   margin: 1.4em 0 0;
   font-size: 1.6em;
   font-family: Bitter, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
   font-weight: 700;
   clear: both;
}
h3 iframe.iframes{
 border: none;
}
section p {
   margin: 1em 0;
}
article figure {
   max-width: 100%;
   margin-left: 2em;
   float: right;
}
article figcaption {
   text-align: center;
}
.Bookkeeping {
 clear: right;
 float: left;
 width: 60%;
}
.Testimonial1 {
    border: 2px solid black;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 16px;
    margin: 16px 0;
 position: relative;
 top: 6em;
}
.Testimonial{
 border: 2px solid black;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 16px;
    margin: 16px 0;
 position: relative;
 top: 6em;
}
.History {
 clear: left;
 float: right;
 width: 47%;
}
.Olddude {
 border-radius: 5px;
 border: 1em solid #B8944D;
 margin: 1em;
 position: relative;
 top: 10em;
}
.nonprofit1 {
 width: 60%;
 clear: left;
 float: right;
}
 
.nonprofit {
 margin: 1em;
 float: left;
 position: relative;
}

/* form styles */
form {
 padding: 10px;
}

/* fieldsset styles */
fieldset {
 margin-bottom: 0.8em;
}
fieldset fieldset {
 margin-top: 1em;
 padding: 0.8em;
 border: 1px solid #777;
}

/* field styles */
.contactinfo input, #stay-nights, textarea {
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
 padding: 0.2em;
 font-size: 1em;
}
select {
 margin-bottom: 0.6em;
}
.contactinfo input {
 position: absolute;
 left: 5em;
}
.schedule input {
 position: absolute;
 left: 10em;
}
#nameinput, #emailinput {
 width: 25em;
}
#phoneinput {
 width: 12em;
}
#stay-nights {
 width: 3em;
}
#submit {
 border: none;
 padding: 0.4em 0.6em;
 background-color: #e3d5ba;
 font-size: 1.25em;
 border-radius: 10px;
}

/* main content table */
th, td {
 border: 1px solid black;
 padding: 0.5em;
}
th {
 background-color: lightblue;
}
.email {
 background-color: ivory;
}

.name {
 background-color: pink;
}
.degree {
 background-color: orange;
}

/* Main Content CSS Table */
.table {
 margin: 1em 0;
 font-size: 1.3em;
 display: table;
}
.row {
 display: table-row;
}
.row div {
 padding: 0.25em 0.5em;
 display: table-cell;
}
.day {
 font-weight: bold;
}

/* label styles */
label {
 font-size: 1em;
 line-height: 1.6em;
}
.contactinfo label {
 display: block;
 position: relative;
 margin: 0.8em 0;
}
.services label, .method label {
 margin-right: 1.6em;
}
.schedule p{
 width: 9.2em;
 float: left;
}
.date-picker label {
 position: absolute;
 left: -10000px;
}
/* footer section */
footer {
   padding: 0.6em;
   background-color: darkblue;
   color: ivory;
   text-align: center;
}
.copyright {
 text-align: center;
 font-size: .8em;
 color: white;
}

/* print styles */
@media print {
   body, h1, article, footer {
      color: rgb(0,0,0);
      background: rgb(255,255,255);
   }
   body {
      max-width: 100%;
   }
   nav {
      display: none;
   }
}
@page {
   margin: 0.75in;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <title>WEB Managing Partners</title>
      <!-- 
         Winter, Edwards, and Boyd (WEB) main web page
         Filename: index.html

         Author:   Justus Self
         Date:     5/2/2017
         A Giant Project that makes me really sad
      -->
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <script src="modernizr.custom.40753.js"></script>
      <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bitter:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
   <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.ico">
   </head>
   <body>
   <div class="container">
   <div id="fb-root"></div>
   <script>(function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.9";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
      <p class="skipnavigation"><a href="#contentstart">Skip navigation</a></p>
      <header>
         <h1><a href="index.html"><img src="images/W.E.B.png" width="501" height="299" alt="Winter, Edwards, &amp; Boyd"></a></h1>
      </header>
      <nav class="sitenavigation">
         <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="aboutus.html">About Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="Services.html">Services</a></li>
   <li><a href="Contact.html">Contact</a></li>
   </ul>
   <ul>
   <li><a href="ManagingPartners.html">Managing Partners</a></li>
   <li><a href="CompanyHistory.html">Company History</a></li>
   <li><a href="CommunityInvolvement.html">Community Involvement</a></li>
         </ul>
   <div class="fb-like" data-href="https://facebook.com/cengagebrain"
   data-layout="button" data-action="like" data-size="small" data-show-faces="true" 
   data-share="false">
  </div>
  <script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+'://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs');</script>
  <a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-text="Sweet BnB in Northern MN" data-show-count="false">Tweet</a><script async src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
      </nav>
   <article id="contentstart">
            <h2>Managing Partners</h2>
            <h3>Our employees may be contacted using the e-mails shown below</h3>
   <br>
   <table>
    <colgroup>
     <col class="name">
     <col class="email">
     <col class="degree">
    </colgroup>
    <thead>
     <tr>
      <th>Employee Name</th>     
      <th>E-mail</th>
      <th>Degree</th>
     </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
     <tr>
      <td>Mike Edwards</td>
      <td><a href="mailto:medwards@webcpa.com">medwards@webcpa.com</a></td>
      <td>Certified Public Accountant</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Julia Winters</td>
      <td><a href="mailto:jwinter@webcpa.com">jwinter@webcpa.com</a></td>
      <td>Certified Financial Planner</td>
     <tr>
      <td>Regina Boyd</td>
      <td><a href="mailto:rboyd@webcpa.com">rboyd@webcpa.com</a></td>
      <td> Certified Public Accountant </td>
     </tr>
    </tbody>
   </table>
   <br>
   <br>
   <footer>
   <nav class="sitenavigation">
     <ul>
     <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
     <li><a href="aboutus.html">About Us</a></li>
     <li><a href="Services.html">Services</a></li>
     <li><a href="Contact.html">Contact</a></li>
     </ul>
     </nav>
     <p class="copyright">&#9400;Justus Self</p>
     <p class="copyright"> CIS 130 – SP16</p>
   </footer>
   </article>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`background` property needs `height` and `(max-)width` just use the values you want and you are good to go.

```css
/* 
   Winter, Edwards, and Boyd style sheet 
   Filename: styles.css

   Author:   Justus Self
   Date:     4/27/2017
   Long giant project
 */


/* reset styles */

html {
  font-size: 16px;
}

a,
article,
audio,
body,
div,
figcaption,
figure,
footer,
header,
h1,
h2,
h3,
img,
li,
nav,
p,
section,
source,
ul,
video {
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

img,
video {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}


/* document-wide styles */

body {
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

p {
  line-height: 1.4em;
  font-size: 1.3em;
}

a:link {
  color: black;
}

a:visited {
  color: #888;
}


/* skip navigation link */

p.skipnavigation a {
  position: absolute;
  left: -10000px;
}

p.skipnavigation a:focus {
  color: ivory;
  background-color: #34180f;
  top: 0.4em;
  left: auto;
  right: 0.4em;
  z-index: 2;
}


/* header section */

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Bitter, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: ivory;
  background-color: white;
  font-size: 2.4em;
}

/* TABLE CENTER*/
table { margin:auto}

/* site navigation bar */

nav {
  color: #34180f;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #B8944D;
}

nav li {
  margin: 0.3em 0.5em;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  line-height: 1.4em;
}

nav a:link {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #744f42;
}

nav a:visited {
  color: #744f42;
}

nav a:hover,
nav a:focus {
  color: ivory;
}

nav ul,
nav div,
nav iframe {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#AboutUs:hover {
  color: ivory;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#AboutUs {
  color: #744f42;
}


/* main content */

article {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 1.4em;
}

article div {
  max-width: 854px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 3% 1em;
  background-color: ivory;
  overflow: auto;
}

article div.welcome {
  padding-top: 2em;
}

article div figure {
  float: left;
  padding-right: 2%;
  padding-bottom: 2% margin-top: 20px;
}

.container {
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 3% 0;
    background: url("http://lorempixel.com/1600/900") no-repeat 0 0 / cover;
  height: 100vh;
  max-width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}

h2 {
  padding: 0.4em;
  text-align: left;
  font-family: Bitter, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
  font-size: 2em;
  font-weight: 700;
}

h3 {
  margin: 1.4em 0 0;
  font-size: 1.6em;
  font-family: Bitter, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  clear: both;
}

h3 iframe.iframes {
  border: none;
}

section p {
  margin: 1em 0;
}

article figure {
  max-width: 100%;
  margin-left: 2em;
  float: right;
}

article figcaption {
  text-align: center;
}

.Bookkeeping {
  clear: right;
  float: left;
  width: 60%;
}

.Testimonial1 {
  border: 2px solid black;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 16px;
  margin: 16px 0;
  position: relative;
  top: 6em;
}

.Testimonial {
  border: 2px solid black;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 16px;
  margin: 16px 0;
  position: relative;
  top: 6em;
}

.History {
  clear: left;
  float: right;
  width: 47%;
}

.Olddude {
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1em solid #B8944D;
  margin: 1em;
  position: relative;
  top: 10em;
}

.nonprofit1 {
  width: 60%;
  clear: left;
  float: right;
}

.nonprofit {
  margin: 1em;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}


/* form styles */

form {
  padding: 10px;
}


/* fieldsset styles */

fieldset {
  margin-bottom: 0.8em;
}

fieldset fieldset {
  margin-top: 1em;
  padding: 0.8em;
  border: 1px solid #777;
}


/* field styles */

.contactinfo input,
#stay-nights,
textarea {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 0.2em;
  font-size: 1em;
}

select {
  margin-bottom: 0.6em;
}

.contactinfo input {
  position: absolute;
  left: 5em;
}

.schedule input {
  position: absolute;
  left: 10em;
}

#nameinput,
#emailinput {
  width: 25em;
}

#phoneinput {
  width: 12em;
}

#stay-nights {
  width: 3em;
}

#submit {
  border: none;
  padding: 0.4em 0.6em;
  background-color: #e3d5ba;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  border-radius: 10px;
}


/* main content table */

th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 0.5em;
}

th {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.email {
  background-color: ivory;
}

.name {
  background-color: pink;
}

.degree {
  background-color: orange;
}


/* Main Content CSS Table */

.table {
  margin: 1em auto;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  display: table;
}

.row {
  display: table-row;
}

.row div {
  padding: 0.25em 0.5em;
  display: table-cell;
}

.day {
  font-weight: bold;
}


/* label styles */

label {
  font-size: 1em;
  line-height: 1.6em;
}

.contactinfo label {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0.8em 0;
}

.services label,
.method label {
  margin-right: 1.6em;
}

.schedule p {
  width: 9.2em;
  float: left;
}

.date-picker label {
  position: absolute;
  left: -10000px;
}


/* footer section */

footer {
  padding: 0.6em;
  background-color: darkblue;
  color: ivory;
  text-align: center;
}

.copyright {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: .8em;
  color: white;
}


/* print styles */

@media print {
  body,
  h1,
  article,
  footer {
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  }
  body {
    max-width: 100%;
  }
  nav {
    display: none;
  }
}

@page {
  margin: 0.75in;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <p class="skipnavigation"><a href="#contentstart">Skip navigation</a></p>
    <header>
      <h1>
        <a href="index.html"><img src="images/W.E.B.png" width="501" height="299" alt="Winter, Edwards, &amp; Boyd"></a>
      </h1>
    </header>
    <nav class="sitenavigation">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="aboutus.html">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="Services.html">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="Contact.html">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="ManagingPartners.html">Managing Partners</a></li>
        <li><a href="CompanyHistory.html">Company History</a></li>
        <li><a href="CommunityInvolvement.html">Community Involvement</a></li>
      </ul>

    </nav>
    <article id="contentstart">
      <h2>Managing Partners</h2>
      <h3>Our employees may be contacted using the e-mails shown below</h3>
      <br>
      <table>
        <colgroup>
          <col class="name">
          <col class="email">
          <col class="degree">
        </colgroup>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Employee Name</th>
            <th>E-mail</th>
            <th>Degree</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>Mike Edwards</td>
            <td><a href="mailto:medwards@webcpa.com">medwards@webcpa.com</a></td>
            <td>Certified Public Accountant</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Julia Winters</td>
            <td><a href="mailto:jwinter@webcpa.com">jwinter@webcpa.com</a></td>
            <td>Certified Financial Planner</td>
            <tr>
              <td>Regina Boyd</td>
              <td><a href="mailto:rboyd@webcpa.com">rboyd@webcpa.com</a></td>
              <td> Certified Public Accountant </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <br>
      <br>
      <footer>
        <nav class="sitenavigation">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="aboutus.html">About Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="Services.html">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="Contact.html">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
        <p class="copyright">&#9400;Justus Self</p>
        <p class="copyright"> CIS 130 – SP16</p>
      </footer>
    </article>
  </div>
```

Comment: Your code helped me find my error was not encapsulating my code in the div class "container1". Thank you for helping me find the area I needed to check. Do you know how I can center the table?

Comment: @SkryBlackfall yup `table { margin: auto}`